# Using a ratio to split data in SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I am trying to update rows in a sql table based on a ratio. The ratio is set in a different table (1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 1:2, 1:3, 2:3 for example)

The table consists of a key number and a status (0 = Run, 3 = Don't Run)

When the table is first populated, all of the Status columns are = 0

Each item in the table will run on either side of the ratio, but never both sides.

[Example Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzlTX.png)

3:1 ratio is shown, but any iteration between 1:1 and 9:9 is possible. Required Data Out1 is always based on the left digit, Required Data Out is always based on the right digit. The table itself is populated daily and the row count changes each day, usually between 800 and 1200 keys.

Google and Stack Exchange show 1,000 different ways to calculate ratios in SQL, but nothing on how to implement them that I could find. Any ideas?

I have tried various permutations of WHILE loops, with mixed results. As long as the total row count can be evenly divided by both numbers in the ratio, as well as the sum of the 2 numbers, I get the results I need. But in most other cases, the Required Data Out1 group is good, but the Required Data Out2 group is skewed by the remainder of the division.

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as text not images) would help immensely

Comment: I tried it as text first, but the formatting got all screwed up so I replaced it with the image.

Comment: Paste it again as three separate tables and I'll sort the formatting out. Please be clear about what is the sample data and what is the expected result because I don't understand it.

Comment: Sample Data = Data In. Expected result is 2 tables, Data Out1 and Data Out2. All 3 tables shown in the image. The incoming data is split based on a ratio, in this case 3:1, but the ratio can be anything from 1:1 to 9:9.

Comment: Don't entirely understand your requirement. But looks like you might need to use [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and/or [Modulus Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by ratios. From your example it appears that you want to select every Nth row - @Squirrel comment should point you in the right direction. If you want more concrete help you need to post some data as text and have another go at explaining your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in the comments earlier, you can use modulus operator to evaluate the required condition for your `DataOut 1` or `2`.

The query below is using `generate_series()` to simulate the `Key` and `Status` of your table is show as column `Status1` (Data Out1) and `Status2` (Data Out2).

If your `Key` is not continuous, you will need to use `row_number()` to generate a continuous running number

```
-- ratio x:y 3:1
declare @x int = 3, @y int = 1;
declare @z int = @x + @y;
  
select [Key] = value,
       Status1 = case when n.n < @x then 0 else 3 end,
       Status2 = case when n.n < @x then 3 else 0 end
from   generate_series(1,10,1) s
       cross apply
       (
           select n = (s.value - 1) % @z
       ) n
```

Result :

| Key | Status1 | Status2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | 0 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 3 |
| 10 | 0 | 3 |